# SuperNotCalledException in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, crash

I'm facing a problem with `SuperNotCalledException` in my code.
 I've an Activity which contains a `NavigationDrawerFragment` and this `Exception` occurs only in "MOTOROLA" device . you can see `raw(Log)`
 [here](http://crashes.to/s/fba044dd229).
So please help me to over come that.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Crashlytics.start(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.decor, null); // "null" is important.

    ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
    View child = decor.getChildAt(0);
    decor.removeView(child);
    sharedHelper = new SharedHelper(LandingActivity.this);

    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) drawer.findViewById(R.id.container); // This is the container we defined just now.
    FrameLayout containerChild = (FrameLayout) drawer.findViewById(R.id.containerChild); // This is the container we defined just now.
    container.removeView(containerChild);
    container.addView(child);
    container.addView(containerChild);
    child.setClickable(true);

    decor.addView(drawer);
    actionBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height_material);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    child.setClickable(true);
    child.setFocusable(true);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.containerChild, new RecentChatFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: just call `super.onCreate()`

Comment: dear super.onCreate() is in my code but still problem is there.any other solution

Comment: nobody sees your code, and the exception says it is not called

Comment: dear,if this is what you are saying,then this will occur with all devices.but "nop".is happening with only motorola's devices.

Comment: no, dont you think that super can be called conditionally? again i see no code since you did not post any: do you still any reliable answer or telling from a crystall ball?

Comment: so please let me how will i can overcome?

Comment: what is the base class of `LandingActivity`?

Comment: another Activity lets say 'A' activity that's extends  Acivity

Comment: so would you post its code? BTW wht do you call `super` inside `try...catch` ?

Comment: dear, do you need any answer or not?

Comment: please let me know ,what you actually want? means code?

Comment: its not me who needs anything, if you dont want to show your base Activity its OK

Comment: base Activity here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=f2c3a76f2f9b691c!890&authkey=!AALf2QRqK6KJh2k&ithint=file%2cjava

Answer (score 0):

You have to call super.onCreate() as the first instruction.